# Multiple onPrepare or dynamic login params when using multiCapabilites

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, selenium, protractor

basically the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163674/can-you-do-multiple-onprepares-per-browser-instance but since there were no answers or comments I'll post again.

I want to login with two user profiles on two separate browsers.

I'd be using something like this in my config file:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: ['profile_1.spec.js'],
    login: {email: 'profile_1',
    password: 'pw1'}
}, {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: ['profile_2.spec.js'],
    login: { email: 'profile_2',
    password: 'pw2'}
}]
```

Since my login page isn't angular I need to use onPrepare and I can only set login params once.

Is there a way pass the login params from the multiCapabilities array to the onPrepare function or to have specific onPrepares inside the multiCapabilities objects?

Answer (score 3):

You can work around this by adding logic in your code.

At protractor 1.7, you can call `browser.getProcessedConfig()`, which returns your config.

You can add arbitrary fields into your browserName.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: ['profile_1.spec.js'],
    name: 'profile1'
}, {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    specs: ['profile_2.spec.js'],
    name: 'profile2'
}]
```

and use params:

```
params: {
    profile1: {
        email: 'CA',
        password: 'pw123'
    },
    profile2: {
        email: 'Sup',
        password: 'pw123'
    }
},
```

Then in on prepare:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
      //do something with browser.params[config.capabilities.name]
    });
},
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait until 1.7 is released. Until then - multiple confs! Unfortunately I can't mark this as answered since I'm waiting for unreleased features.

Comment: Yup, just giving you a heads up here.

Comment: Fyi, protractor 1.7 is out